# Django - add widget option in form.py Meta class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, meta

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from second_app.models import user

class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = '__all__'
```

In a normal `forms.py` that doesn't inherit from the models, you can use `field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)` to specify how the input field will be displayed to the users. How can this be done, when my `forms.py` is inheriting the class defined in `models.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for this meta's [`widgets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) option:

```
from django import forms
from second_app.models import user

class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'field_name': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the widget in the form `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NewUserForm, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
    self.fields['fieldname'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

You can change anything about the field.. eg. required, choices, and many other things that you may want to decide differently at the time the form is displayed.  You can also delete fields from the form here, or add fields you might only want included conditionally.. eg.:

```
del self.fields['fieldname']
if some_condition:
    field['new_fieldname'] = forms.CharField()
```